# Can I use Bluetooth on Blackberries to create local multiplayer?

Tags: blackberry, bluetooth, multiplayer

I'm developing a game for Blackberry, and I've been tasked with developing multiplayer for it. I've been trying to do research and find out how to implement bluetooth on Blackberries and I want to know if it's feasible to implement on a turn based game. Also, if anyone could give me some resources or tutorials to being with, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would definitely work.  Check out the BluetoothDemo sample app that comes with the developer tools.  It contains code that lets you communicate between two devices using Bluetooth.